# Beautiful Soup cannot find class which exists on web page

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape https://www.espn.com/nba/scoreboard
There is a sort of date object there which contains links to box scores of previously played games.

I have tried :

```
divs = soup.find('div',class_='datepicker datepicker-dropdown datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-top')

print(divs)
```

> output is: None

Other classes can be found, but for some reason this class cannot.
I think it has something to do with the fact that this class is related to a calendar which pops up within the web page (without changing the url).

Comment: Have you tried searching for the div in the html that your script has?

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely there

Comment: Can you show us the source your script is searching? :)

Comment: <div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-top" style="top: 35px; left: 0px; display: block;">

Comment: I hope that's what you meant..

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that some portion of HTML is added by .js script **dynamically** after the page is loaded.

If this is the case you won't be able to load it using soup...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
import bs4

html = """<div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-top" style="top: 35px; left: 0px; display: block;">"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

class_ = "datepicker datepicker-dropdown datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-top".split(" ")
divs = [div for div in soup.find_all("div") if all(x in div.attrs["class"] for x in class_)]

print(divs)
```

Output:

```
[<div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-top" style="top: 35px; left: 0px; display: block;"></div>]
```